# How to calculate Active user which is any user with usage >= 100, and based on Last 12 months of data

Tags: python, pandas

the code below is outputting the total months a unique user id is in, and counting the total. What I need is to calculate active users based on usage level >= 100 for the last 12 months using the log-in month and year.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as ny
import sqldf as sqldf

#raw_data="data_python.xlsx"

df_raw = pd.read_excel(r"data_python.xlsx")


print (df_raw)

result = df_raw.groupby(["Usage","Month","Year"])["User ID"].nunique()


Active_Users = df_raw.groupby(["Usage","Month","Year"])["User ID"].apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.values))
Active_Users  = Active_Users.reset_index()

Active_Users  = pd.concat([Active_Users] + [Active_Users["Usage"].shift(i) for i in range(1, 12)], axis ="columns")
Active_Users.columns = ["User ID","Month","Year"] + [ f"shift_{i}" for i in range(12) ]

def count_unique(row):
    total_set = frozenset()
    columns = [ f"shift_{i}" for i in range(12) ]
    for col in columns:
        if row.get(col) and type(row.get(col)) == frozenset:
            total_set = total_set | row.get(col)
    return len(total_set)

Active_Users["T_Months_Usage"] = Active_Users.apply(count_unique, axis=1)
Active_Users
```

I have tried changing the usage and month variables but it is still counting months rather than individuals usage how do I supplement these 2 fields?

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.